# How to update new migrations changes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In entity framework core I have created an initial migration using following command

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
dotnet ef database update
```

With this command the database created with the some intial tables from C# entity classes.

Then I am trying to add new C# entity classes (or in future update my entity classes ).

I need to update the database with the newer changes. How I can do it?

When trying to apply same command again

```
   dotnet ef migrations add NameOfNewScript
   dotnet ef database update
```

With first command the changes getting reflected in code and new migration file also created in migration folder.
But with the second command I am getting error:

> An object already exists in database. (for which already created first time)

But it works when drop the database manually and then apply the command.

So how we can manage this without droping the database and apply only post changes?

Comment: Does 2nd migration contains creation of objects which are created in first migration already?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the -force command? 
i.e: 
add-migration -InitialCreate
update-databas

Answer (score 0):

dotnet ef database update NameOfNewScript -v

Try this.
Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the table "__EFMigrationsHistory" in your db. You might have deleted and recreated your InitialCreate migration after updating. In this case ef sees it as new and tries to apply it too.

If there is a difference between migration id of your code and db, you should either purge your db and start clean (if there is nothing but some testing data) or change the id in the history table and check the database if everthing is as it should be.

| MigrationId | ProductVersion |
| --- | --- |
| 20210728111143_Initial | 5.0.6 |

vs

```
20210903073446_Initial.cs
```